# Elasticsearch Performance Analysis

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

We are currently evaluating Elasticsearch as our solution for Analytics. The main driver is the fact that once the data is populated into Elasticsearch, the reporting comes for free with Kibana.

Before adopting it, I am tasked to do a performance analysis of the tool.

The main requirement is supporting a PUT rate of 500 evt/sec.

I am currently starting with a small setup as follows just to get a sense of the API before I upload that to a more serious lab.

My Strategy is basically, going over CSVs of analytics that correspond to the format I need and putting them into elasticsearch. I am not using the bulk API because in reality the events will not arrive in a bulk fashion.

Following is the main code that does this:

```
        // Created once, used for creating a JSON from a bean
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Creating a measurement for checking the count of sent events vs
        // ES stored events
        AnalyticsMetrics metrics = new AnalyticsMetrics();
        metrics.startRecording();

        File dir = new File(mFolder);
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {

            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()), '|');
            String [] nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                AnalyticRecord record = new AnalyticRecord();
                record.serializeLine(nextLine);

                // Generate json
                String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(record);

                IndexResponse response = mClient.getClient().prepareIndex("sdk_sync_log", "sdk_sync")
                        .setSource(json)
                        .execute()
                        .actionGet();

                // Recording Metrics
                metrics.sent();

            }
        }

        metrics.stopRecording();

        return metrics;
```

I have the following questions:

1. How do I know through the API when all the requests are completed and the data is saved into Elasticsearch? I could query Elasticsearch for the objects counts in my particular index but doing that would be a new performance factor by itself, hence I am eliminating this option.
2. Is the above the fastest way to insert object to Elasticsearch or are there other optimizations I could do. Keep in mind the bulk API is not an option for now.

Thx in advance.

P.S: the Elasticsearch version I am using on both client and server is 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

1. Elasticsearch index response has `isCreated()` method that returns `true` if the document is a new one or `false` if it has been updated and can be used to see if the document was successfully inserted/updated.
2. If bulk indexing is not an option there are other areas that could be tweaked to improve performance like

   - increasing index refresh interval using `index.refresh_interval`
   - disabling replicas by setting `index.number_of_replicas` to 0
   - Disabling [_source](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) and [_all](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) fields if they are not needed.